# Updating values in text widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to update the values in the same Tkinter window for some other data after 10 seconds without closing that window. I've tried using the `after` method of Tkinter, but it is not working for my purpose. `depth_chart` is an array with 3 columns and multiple rows that need to be displayed in this window.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Depth Ladder")

height = len(depth_chart)
width = len(depth_chart[0])
Label(root, text = "Bid Quantity").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(root, text = "Price").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Label(root, text = "Ask Quantity").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        a= str(depth_chart[i][j])
        b = Text(root,height =1)
        if a != "None":
            b.insert(INSERT,a)
        if j ==0:
            b.config(bg="green",fg = "white",relief = RIDGE,width =8)
        elif j==1:
            b.config(background="black",fg = "white",relief = RIDGE,width =12)
        elif j ==2:
            b.config(background="red",fg = "white",relief = RIDGE,width =8)
        b.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"I've tried using the `after` method of Tkinter, but it is not working for my purpose"* Can you provide more details about how it is not working... show us the error...

Comment: show code with `after()`

Comment: you can always try to use `root.update()` to force `mainloop()` to update data in widgets and redraw them.

Comment: maybe first create grid with empty Text and later update text in all `Text` - and then you can update widgets in `function()`  which at the end will run `after(10000, function)` to run te same `function()` after 10 seconds.

Comment: how do you update data in `depth_chart` ? It makes problem when you run GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create grid with empty widgets `Text` and keep them on 2D list.

And later you could run function which removes old data from widgets `Text` and put new data. And at the end it should use `after()` to run itself again after 10s.

Problem can make code which gets new data in `depth_chart` but you didn't show this part so I simulate changes in `depth_chart`

---

In this example I create random data and update every 1s.

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random  # simulate changes in data

# --- functions ---

def fill_text():
    global depth_chart

    for y, row in enumerate(depth_chart):
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            # remove previous text
            all_text[y][x].delete('0.1', 'end')
            # add new text
            if item is not None:
                all_text[y][x].insert('insert', item)

    # simulate changes in data                
    depth_chart = [[random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(3)] for y in range(10)]

    # fill it again after 1s (1000ms)
    root.after(1000, fill_text)
    
# --- main ---

# simulate changes in data
depth_chart = [[random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(3)] for y in range(10)]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Depth Ladder")

tk.Label(root, text="Bid Quantity").grid(row=0, column=0)  # PEP8: without spaces around `=`
tk.Label(root, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Ask Quantity").grid(row=0, column=2)

# create grid with empty widgets `Text` and remember them on 2D list
all_text = []
for y, row in enumerate(depth_chart, 1): 
    row_text = []
    for x, item in enumerate(row):
        text = tk.Text(root, height=1)
        text.grid(row=y, column=x)
        
        if x == 0:
            text.config(bg="green", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)
        elif x == 1:
            text.config(bg="black", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=12)
        elif x == 2:
            text.config(bg="red", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)

        row_text.append(text)

    all_text.append(row_text)
        
# fill it first time        
fill_text()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have different number of rows in `depth_chart` every 10s then it will be easier to remove all `Text` from grid and create again new widgets - and then you can add values directly when `Text` is created.

It has one problem - it **blinks** when all widgets are removes.

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random  # simulate changes in data

# --- functions ---

def fill_text():
    global depth_chart
    global all_text

    # simulate changes in data                
    number_of_rows = random.randint(5, 20)
    depth_chart = [[random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(3)] for y in range(number_of_rows)]
    
    # delete old text widgets
    for row in all_text: 
        for item in row:
            item.destroy()
            
    # clear list
    all_text = []
    
    # create grid with widgets `Text` and remember them on 2D list
    for y, row in enumerate(depth_chart, 1): 
        row_text = []
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            text = tk.Text(root, height=1)
            text.grid(row=y, column=x)
            
            if x == 0:
                text.config(bg="green", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)
            elif x == 1:
                text.config(bg="black", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=12)
            elif x == 2:
                text.config(bg="red", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)

            if item is not None:
                text.insert('insert', item)
    
            row_text.append(text)
    
        all_text.append(row_text)

    # fill it again after 1s (1000ms)
    root.after(1000, fill_text)
    
# --- main ---

# place for all text widgets
all_text = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Depth Ladder")

tk.Label(root, text="Bid Quantity").grid(row=0, column=0)  # PEP8: without spaces around `=`
tk.Label(root, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Ask Quantity").grid(row=0, column=2)
        
# fill it first time        
fill_text()

root.mainloop()
```

---

To resolve problem with blinking it would need more complex code which remove or add only needed rows.

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random  # simulate changes in data

# --- functions ---

def fill_text():
    global depth_chart
    global all_text

    # simulate changes in data                
    number_of_rows = random.randint(5, 20)
    depth_chart = [[random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(3)] for y in range(number_of_rows)]

    # calculate how many rows add or delete        
    len_chart = len(depth_chart)
    len_all   = len(all_text)
    diff = len_chart - len_all
    
    #print(number_of_rows, diff)
    
    if diff < 0:
        # delete widgets
        for row in all_text[diff:]: 
            for item in row:
                item.destroy()
        all_text = all_text[:diff]
    elif diff > 0:
        # add widgets
        for y in range(len_all+1, len_chart+1):
            
            text1 = tk.Text(root, height=1)
            text1.grid(row=y, column=0)
            text1.config(bg="green", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)

            text2 = tk.Text(root, height=1)
            text2.grid(row=y, column=1)
            text2.config(bg="black", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=12)

            text3 = tk.Text(root, height=1)
            text3.grid(row=y, column=2)
            text3.config(bg="red", fg="white", relief='ridge', width=8)

            all_text.append([text1, text2, text3])
                
    # put values in `Text`            
    for y, row in enumerate(depth_chart):
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            # remove previous text
            all_text[y][x].delete('0.1', 'end')
            # add new text
            if item is not None:
                all_text[y][x].insert('insert', item)

    # fill it again after 1s (1000ms)
    root.after(1000, fill_text)
    
# --- main ---

# place for all text widgets
all_text = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Depth Ladder")

tk.Label(root, text="Bid Quantity").grid(row=0, column=0)  # PEP8: without spaces around `=`
tk.Label(root, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Ask Quantity").grid(row=0, column=2)
        
# fill it first time        
fill_text()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works but the depth_chart has different no of rows and inserting more values than initial values is giving list index out of range error. so how can I modify fill_text() for varying no of rows of depth chart?

Comment: my code works with any size of `depth_chart` - but you have to use real `depth_chart` at start (not my `depth_chart` created with `random`)

Comment: if `depth_chart` may has different number of rows every 10s then you will have rather delete all Text and create them again with new number of rows.

Comment: how can i display streaming data in this format,i.e, the exact time interval after which data needs to be changed varies according to streaming data. Therfore, I can't use after() method. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know what stream you have but I would try to use `after()` for this because it is standard method in all GUIs - even if you read video stream. If you can't use `after()`  then you can try to run code in thread but most GUIs doesn't like to change widgets data in thread so it need to send data to main thread using `queue` and then you need to use `after()` to check if there are new data in `queue` and update widgets. So finally you still need `after()` and better try to do it all in `after()` without `thread`.